# Value Count String Occurrences for Pandas Column of Lists type in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas column that contains a list of strings that are separated by a comma and a new line " \n " if the list has multiple strings. Otherwise, the notation is simply: [\n "string" \n] (notice how each new string has a \n proceeding it)

Is it possible, for the entire column, count the number of times each string occurs?

```
     Outcomes
0   [\n "springs"\n]
1   [\n "to_do"\n]
2   [\n "replace"\n]
3   [\n "null"\n]
4   [\n "finance"\n]
5   [\n "finance"\n]
6   [\n "project_management" ,\n "sprints...
7   [\n "to_do" ,\n "finance...
8   [\n "remote"\n]
9   [\n "get_it_done"\n]
10  [\n "get_it_done" ,\n "remote...
```

Target output should be like the following:

```
Outcomes      Value_count
springs            21
to_do              12
replace            2
null               1
finance            24
project_management 12
get_it_done        22
```

Tried to do something like the following but getting an error due to the object type not being iterable

```
pd.Series([x for item in df['Outcomes'] for x in item]).value_counts()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) first:

```
s = df['Outcomes'].str.split(',').explode().str.strip('[] ').value_counts()
```

Or convert values to lists by `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
pd.Series([x.strip() for item in df['Outcomes'] for x in ast.literal_eval(item)]).value_counts()
```